# Does the linked service support dynamic json in azure data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Currently, I'm trying to set up a dynamic key vault linked service.
Unfortunately, whatever I try I'm not able to successfully test the connection.

```
{
    "name": "AzureKeyVault1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "AzureKeyVault",
        "typeProperties": {
            "baseUrl": {
                "value": "@concat('https://vault.azure.net','/')",
                "type": "Expression"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code using concat is not a real use case but just a way to test if dynamic json is possible for linked service.
I was expecting (based on the documentation) that I could make the baseUrl property dynamic. Am I using the right formatting?

I get the following error:

Error: Error: Can't get property concat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wim,based on the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/parameterize-linked-services),parameterize linked services only supports below services,not including Azure Key Vault.

[image]

You could submit feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory) to push some improvements of azure data factory you want.

Comment: In the documentation it states: "For all other data stores, you can parameterize the linked service by selecting the Code icon on the Connections tab and using the JSON editor."

I guess a key vault is not a data store but I would have expected that this wouldn't make a difference. Thx for your reply.

Comment: @Wim You're welcome.If you think my answer helps you,would you please mark it?Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

@Wim

To Answer your question, this is the correct formatting.

I have been able to parameterize a pipeline parameter, and then pass it as the baseurl in a dynamic expression.

Comment: Can you share the solution?